# php, refreshing ReflectionClass after dynamic change

Tags: php, reflection

I'm trying to build a tool that add/remove methods for me in a class, basically saving me the  time to type some standard methods I use in my framework.

However, it seems to me that the **getMethods** method of the ReflectionClass uses some sort of cache, because if I call **getMethods** once, then change the methods dynamically (for instance replacing the class file with another one with the same class name but different methods), then call **getMethods** again, it doesn't take into account my dynamic changes.

I tried **sleep**, but it was obviously not that.

I was wondering if there is a way (but I'm afraid there is not) in php to "refresh" the ReflectionClass, so that it can "reflect" on the actual content rather than on some sort of cache.

As a work around, I can rely on tokens, but that requires a bit more work than just using the Reflection classes, so it would be great if I could "reset" the Reflection cache somehow.

Comment: *basically saving me the time to type some standard methods I use in my framework.* this sounds like something inheritance is supposed to be for.

Comment: @Nigel Ren. I have my reasons to prefer code generation rather than inheritance in this case: I want to have an "à la carte" generation tool, inheritance is not as flexible for what I'm trying to achieve (lot of different methods in lots of different domains), basically I'm building a developer wizard for some patterns I have identified from my own coding style.

Comment: @ling can you say something more about "replacing the class file with another one". You cannot require/redeclare the same class. Do you mean physically replace the contents of file while it executes? I dont think this has even effect on calling the methods not mentioning reflection.

Comment: @blahy, yes exactly: physically replacing the contents of the file while the php process is running. So for instance calling reflection on file at t=1, tnen during the same script change the file content with something like unlink and file_put_contents for instance, then using reflection again, on the same file, but at t=2, and reflection is showing the content of the file at t=1.

Comment: @ling i thought about what you wrote and still dont know exactly how you replace the class because i think its not possible. Please take a look at my answer and if my assumptions are wrong update your question with the actual code where your class with updated code is working but reflection is not.

Comment: @blahy, thanks for your answer. I'm not saying reflection doesn't work, I'm just trying to find a way to add/remove methods from a file. I will give you the valid point, because of the effort you put in your answer, I might also try runkit, thanks for the suggestion. But then if that doesn't work for me, I'll have to back to using tokens. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: One more idea is to use __call to add/remove methods dynamically. class with __call and addMethod(string $name, callable $callable). You add your function/method with addMethod and then check in __call if it is registered. You can pass $this to that callable also. But i dont see this happening on file level - only if you generate the code and then use it in next requests, but not in the same one. But its just my take on the answer!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, I thought again about it, and I know how I'm going to do that. Basically my current method for retrieving method info is this: https://github.com/lingtalfi/ClassCooker/blob/master/doc/api/Ling/ClassCooker/ClassCooker/getMethodsBasicInfo.md, but it's based on reflection which does not handle dynamic file changes. So I will just replace the content of that method with a token based method, I'll tweak this class for that (https://github.com/lingtalfi/TokenFun/blob/master/TokenFinder/MethodTokenFinder.php), and  I'm using Bat/FileTool for file manip (out of char

Comment: following my comment above, (no more chars). So yes, I'll be using Bat/FileTool: https://github.com/lingtalfi/Bat/blob/master/FileTool.md, which has lots of methods to insert/replace content in files, based on the line numbers, which my technique is based on. And so reflection gives the line numbers for most things, but so does token based technique, so that will work too. By the way, token based technique can go deeper than reflection, for instance with token based technique we can get the line numbers for docBlock comments, which Reflection doesn't provide.

Comment: folllowing on my comment above (again no more chars). It's just that reflection is built-in, so you don't have nothing to do, you can just use those methods, while with token based methods, you have to create yourself first, but in they end they can do whatever you want (i.e. more control).

Comment: Actually I forgot, but in this class: https://github.com/lingtalfi/TokenFun/blob/master/TokenFinder/Tool/TokenFinderTool.php, I have a method called getMethodsInfo, based on tokens, and which returns already half of the info I need (I just need to add some line numbers to be good). I'm going to tweak that today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the constraints you have I dont see a way to do this natively.

Maybe you can consider using runkit https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-method-redefine.php because it would seem to be possible (and maybe it will suit your needs) but I'll stick to base PHP in my answer.

You never use reflection on a file, you use reflection on a class/function, etc. so on code level. And to use reflection on a class you have to declare it first (require, autoload, etc.) and once it is declared thats it, you cannot redeclare it. Trying to require file with the same class will result in an error.

So requiring a file with a class, using the class and then changing the file itself will have no effect. Take a look at the code:

```
<?php

file_put_contents('a.php', '<?php class A {function a() {return "a";}}');

require('a.php');

$a = new A();
var_dump($a->a());

file_put_contents('a.php', '<?php class A {function b() {return "b";}}');

$a = new A();
var_dump($a->b());
```

Not even mentioning reflection at this point - how would you make this code print 'b'? You will get `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method A::b() in ...` because defined version is still the one you required. Requiring file again will result in `PHP Fatal error:  Cannot declare class A, because the name is already in use in ...`.

So I think reflection is working correctly.